# Copy all Chrome settings and data from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, google-chrome, copy

After installing Ubuntu <kbd>**16.04**</kbd> on a brand new computer, I tried to copy all Google Chrome data (Extensions, Bookmarks, Passwords, ...) from my old <kbd>**14.04**</kbd>.

Especially extensions, since there's a lot of them!

Both <kbd>**14.04**</kbd> and <kbd>**16.04**</kbd> have the same user name (*ring0*) and ID (1000).

Copied (`cp -pr` as root [while the files belong to *ring0* anyway])

```
~ring0/.config/google-chrome
~ring0/.cache/google-chrome
~ring0/.gnome/apps/chrome*
```

and even

```
 /opt/google
```

after a proper install (just in case a key is stored somewhere)

But, while the bookmarks have been recovered automatically (thanks to the login to Google Gmail et al.),

- Have to log back in to all sites (eg this one)
- No extension has been copied

Since I'm root on both machines, and have access to "Show passwords" in the settings anyway, is there a way to copy and get everything, including extensions, without having to login again?

Comment: If you ever used any Google service with the older, all of that (and more) is synchronized immediately after you login in the new one with your Google account.

Comment: Thanks but since the files are physically in the `google-chrome extensions` dir, I'm trying to find a way to see the extensions without logging in.

Comment: Your copy-destination looks strange, when you are logged in as `ring0` then copy to `~/.config/google-chrome`, not to `~ring0/.config/google-chrome`...

Comment: @mook765 being logged in as `ring0`, using `~` or `~ring0` is the same.

Comment: OK, never see that before, good to know...Doesn't the ownership change to root when you copy as root?

Comment: @mook765  cp -**p**r

Comment: I see, `-p`-option, missed that...